# GraphQL query in .NET Core returning empty result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, graphql

I currently have one simple query (`ArticleQuery`) set up which includes two fields. The first field takes an id and returns the appropriate data-this field functions as I'd expect and works. The second field (named `articles`) should be returning all objects in the table however when issuing the below query with the `GraphiQL` interface, I'm being returned an empty string.

Query:

```
query GetArticleData(){
  articles {
    id
    description
  }
}
```

Where `ArticleQuery` looks as follows:

```
    public class ArticleQuery : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public ArticleQuery(IArticleService articleService)
        {
            Field<ArticleType>(
                name: "article",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "id" }),
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    var id = context.GetArgument<int>("id");
                    return articleService.Get(id);
                }
            );

            Field<ListGraphType<ArticleType>>(
                name: "articles",
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    return articleService.GetAll();
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Note that breakpoints set inside the `articleService.GetAll()` method are never hit.

And finally, the `ArticleType` class:

```
    public class ArticleType : ObjectGraphType<ArticleViewModel>
    {
        public ArticleType()
        {
            Field(x => x.Id).Description("Id of an article.");
            Field(x => x.Description).Description("Description of an article.");
        }
    }
```

why is my query returning an empty string instead of my list of articles and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more playing around, it looks like the formatting of my query was incorrect. It should have been:

```
query GetArticleData{
  articles {
    id
    description
  }
}
```

instead of:

```
query GetArticleData(){
  articles {
    id
    description
  }
}
```

as the parenthesis are only needed when specifying query variables and need to be excluded otherwise.